# How do you Populate ListView With SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite, simplecursoradapter

My program crashes every time I try to run this method:

```
private void populateListView() {
    Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllRows();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] from = new String[] {ProductContract.ProductEntry.INPUT, ProductContract.ProductEntry.DATE};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.t_input, R.id.t_date};

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.display_row, cursor, from, to, 0);
    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.display_listview);
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}
```

Here's my getAllRows method:

```
public Cursor getAllRows() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query(true, ProductContract.ProductEntry.TABLE_NAME, ProductContract.ProductEntry.ALL_KEYS,
            null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Please add [mcve]. There is plenty of reasons for the app to crash

Comment: please post the logcat

Comment: `My program crashes` doesn't tell us much.